# R mlogit-Error system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number

Tags: r, mixed-models, mlogit

I am using library(mlogit) in R and I am stuck at this particular data set which looks like this

```
 CustomerID Item Price Calories Choice
           1  200  1.99      490    NO 
           1  312  4.99      887    NO 
           1  560  5.19      910    NO 
           1  700  4.79      690    NO 
           1  909  4.89      660    NO 
           1 1705  4.00      840    NO
```

There are 187 items in total and 4 customerID(1,2,3 and 4). Each customer is presented with a choice set of 187 items from which he selects one based on Price and Calories. The price and calories remain the same for 4 customers.

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   748 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ CustomerID: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Item      : Factor w/ 187 levels "200","231","232",..: 1 11 14 15 18 25 33 34 36 39 ...
 $ Price     : num  1.99 4.99 5.19 4.79 4.89 4 4 4 4 6.21 ...
 $ Calories  : int  490 887 910 690 660 840 1638 1559 1530 1559 ...
 $ Choice    : Factor w/ 2 levels "NO ","YES": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I format the data according to mlogit command in the manner below:-

```
m<- mlogit.data(data, choice="Choice", shape="long", alt.levels=c("200",    "231",    "232",    "240",.....(*all the 187 'Item' here)*))
```

which gives me this:-

```
head(m)
      CustomerID Item Price Calories Choice
1.200          1  200  1.99      490    NO 
1.231          1  231  1.19      320    YES
1.232          1  232  1.49      320    NO 
1.240          1  240  4.79      590    NO 
1.250          1  250  2.39      490    NO 
1.253          1  253  4.49      691    NO
```

My dataset is ordered by CutomerID and Item as I had read in a previous question that it might cause an issue.

I try several formulas but none of them runs

```
Tr.ml <- mlogit(Choice ~0|Price+Calories|0,m)
Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[548,548] = 0
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

The correlation between Price and Calories is about 43%

```
cor(m$Price,m$Calories)
[1] 0.429796
```

I also tried this:-

```
Tr.ml <- mlogit(Choice ~Price+Calories,m)
Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.06243e-23
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Can anyone provide some thoughts on resolving this error? I have been at it for 2 weeks now.